# Override ValidatorOnChange(event) in Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

i have asp.net webapplication.

i have used RequiredFieldValidator to validate the Textbox.

i have used ValidatorOnChange(event) onblur event of textbox as follows :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" runat="server" CssClass="txtBoxWidthMiddle txtSingleline txtBack-Color txtRequireBorder-Color required"
 MaxLength="50" TabIndex="2" onblur="ValidatorOnChange(event);"></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvFname" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFname"
ErrorMessage="First Name is required" ValidationGroup="a" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

my question is is it possible to override ValidatorOnChange(event) method ? i want to call a function based on ValidatorOnChange(event) method return result(true or false).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the onblur event of the textbox you can use any js function. For example, I created a function that is the one that actually calls the ValidatorOnChange(...). You could change the ValidatorOnChange(...) function to match your needs.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="myValidatorOnChange(event);"></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myValidatorOnChange(event) {
        var result = ValidatorOnChange(event);

        return result;
    }

</script>
```